# How to load data in a record set from a table?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, tool-validation

I'm developing a python tool in ArcGIS 10.3 .I want to show selected record that are result of the select by attribute. 
Is it possible to show the selected records in the record set ?

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    fc = self.params[0].value
    lineCode = self.params[1].value
    recordset = self.params[2].value

    whereClause = 'Number =%s ' % int(lineCode)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)

    #  Here i want to load the selected records in a record set ........ !??

    return

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return
```

[image]

Comment: Just thinking off the top of my head, so may be a red herring, but I would have thought you then have a search cursor reading the selection and then populating the recordset, if one can actually write to a recordset (never personally done it).

Comment: @Hornbydd i know search cursor but I could write the records in recordset and could not find any snippet about this subject. The main problem is writing the records in the recordset

Answer (score 1):

Below is some code that shows you how to populate a FeatureSet, this code was run in pyscripter so you would need to adapt it to your toolbox python script.

I did a before and after count to prove that only a subset of data was used to populate the FeatureSet. It appears the load method does not honor selections so this is why I wrote it to an in_memory workspace.

```py
import arcpy
try:
    infc = r"C:\Scratch\ghsrtmpoints.shp"
    n = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(infc).getOutput(0))
    print "input count = " + str(n)
    arcpy.Select_analysis(infc, "in_memory/myLayer", """"GRID_CODE" >= 100""")
    fs = arcpy.FeatureSet()
    fs.load("in_memory/myLayer")
    n = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fs).getOutput(0))
    print "selected = " + str(n)
    print "Finished!"
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
finally:
    arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory/myLayer")
    del fs
```

**EDIT**

Further research suggests it may not be possible to load a recordset which is also a parameter, as discussed in this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40466/how-to-load-a-record-set-parameter-in-a-tool-dialog).

If you are looking for a table like structure as a parameter may be you could explore the [ValueTable](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm) parameter.

Comment: Horbby dd  your code work fine without using GUI but i couldn't use the record set parameter in the python tool and show the records in it.Is it possible to show the records in the GUI?Thanks

Comment: Suppose the input is a table in a gdb not the feature class and the record set shows all of records not the selected. I think it's more simple than your code. If i can show all of  the records in GUI,so i can show selected records. Are there any solution instead of record set?

Comment: Hornbydd you are right . i should use ValueTable parameter. Thanks any way

Comment: Hornby dd. Please edit your answer and write your comment about Value Table. This is the beset solution. Your answer will helpful for others and I'll mark it